# Download de arquivo zip de uma URL

Tags: c#, arquivo-zip

Boa noite, preciso fazer o download de um arquivo zip e salvar em um servidor, entretanto, com o código que estou utilizando abaixo, ele apenas cria o arquivo zip no servidor; ao abri-lo, não há nenhum arquivo nele e é dada a seguinte mensagem: Unsupported ARCHIVE type.

Dentro desse arquivo zip, temos dois arquivos json. Ao chamar a URL pelo browser, ele faz o download automaticamente.

```
            var localPath = @"\\nomeServidor\\nomepasta\\" + nomeArquivo;

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), localPath);

            while (webClient.IsBusy) { }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar em possíveis soluções?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa fazer essa gambiarra com while, pode usar o DownloadFile sem ser async, pois você não precisa dele async.

No caso, seu código ficaria:

```
  var localPath = @"\\nomeServidor\\nomepasta\\" + nomeArquivo;
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    client.DownloadFile(localPath);
  }
```

Esse código deve funcionar pois até onde sei o downloadfile não faz distinção de tipo de arquivo. Caso não funcione, confira se não é um problema no arquivo baixado ou se o usuário executando o programa tem permissões para acessar o localPath.

Comment: Paulo, alterei o código, mas infelizmente não deu certo. Estou executando local em minha máquina e tenho acesso a pasta, entretanto ele grava um arquivo zip vazio.

Comment: Tente exigir permissões de administrador para executar seu programa. Para fazer isso, adicione a seguinte linha no manifest de sua aplicação:
 `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
`

Comment: Ainda nada.. :/

Comment: Qual o erro? poderia dar mais informações? Consegue baixar o arquivo normalmente pelo browser?

Comment: Não dá erro algum na aplicação. Pelo browser, o arquivo é baixado normalmente, com o seu conteúdo correto. Pela aplicação, é criado um arquivo zip só que sem conteúdo. Será que pode ser algo relacionado à permissão ao link?

Comment: Paulo, problema resolvido rsrs Realmente era a autenticação. Tão besta que nem dá pra acreditar kkkkk Obrigada!

Comment: Não foi nada, pode marcar a resposta como certa? Isso ajuda a comunidade :)